# Error no guarda datos en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando ingreso datos en el formulario y envío, me responde como exitosa, incluso guarda las imágenes en las carpetas, pero no guarda nada en la base de datos. No sé cuál sea el error

```
<?php
$miconexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","online");



if($_FILES['imagen-slider']['error']){

    switch ($_FILES['imagen-slider']['error']) {
        case 1: //Error exceso de tamaño de archivo en php.ini
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor";
        break;

        case 2: //Error tamaño archivo marcado desde el formulario
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede 2MB";

        case 3: //Corrupción de archivo
        echo "El envío de archivo se interrumpió";
        break;

        case 4: // no hay fichero
        echo "No se ha enviado ningún archivo";
        break;
    }
}else{

    echo "Entrada subida correctamente</br>";

    if((isset($_FILES['imagen-slider']['name']) && ($_FILES['imagen-slider']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK))){

        $destino_de_ruta = "images/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen-slider']['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES['imagen-slider']['name']);

        echo "El archivo " . $_FILES['imagen-slider']['name'] . "se ha copiado en el directorio de imágenes";
    }else{
        echo "El archivo no se ha podido copiar al directorio de imágenes";
    }
}

//Probamos nuevo código

if($_FILES['fponente']['error']){

    switch ($_FILES['fponente']['error']) {
        case 1: //Error exceso de tamaño de archivo en php.ini
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor";
        break;

        case 2: //Error tamaño archivo marcado desde el formulario
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede 2MB";

        case 3: //Corrupción de archivo
        echo "El envío de archivo se interrumpió";
        break;

        case 4: // no hay fichero
        echo "No se ha enviado ningún archivo";
        break;
    }
}else{

    echo "Entrada subida correctamente</br>";

    if((isset($_FILES['fponente']['name']) && ($_FILES['fponente']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK))){

        $destino_de_ruta = "images/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fponente']['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES['fponente']['name']);

        echo "El archivo " . $_FILES['fponente']['name'] . "se ha copiado en el directorio de imágenes";
    }else{
        echo "El archivo no se ha podido copiar al directorio de imágenes";
    }
}

if($_FILES['imagen-video']['error']){

    switch ($_FILES['imagen-video']['error']) {
        case 1: //Error exceso de tamaño de archivo en php.ini
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede lo permitido por el servidor";
        break;

        case 2: //Error tamaño archivo marcado desde el formulario
        echo "El tamaño del archivo excede 2MB";

        case 3: //Corrupción de archivo
        echo "El envío de archivo se interrumpió";
        break;

        case 4: // no hay fichero
        echo "No se ha enviado ningún archivo";
        break;
    }
}else{

    echo "Entrada subida correctamente</br>";

    if((isset($_FILES['imagen-video']['name']) && ($_FILES['imagen-video']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK))){

        $destino_de_ruta = "images/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen-video']['tmp_name'], $destino_de_ruta . $_FILES['imagen-video']['name']);

        echo "El archivo " . $_FILES['imagen-video']['name'] . "se ha copiado en el directorio de imágenes";
    }else{
        echo "El archivo no se ha podido copiar al directorio de imágenes";
    }
}


$slider=$_FILES['imagen-slider']['name'];
$fponente=$_FILES['fponente']['name'];
$imagenvideo=$_FILES['imagen-video']['name'];
$imacto=$_POST['timpacto'];
$subimpacto=$_POST['subimpact'];
$valoracion=$_POST['valoracion'];
$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
$aprendere=$_POST['aprendere'];
$requisitos=$_POST['requisitos'];
$url=$_POST['url-video'];
$titulo=$_POST['campo_titulo'];
$oferta=$_POST['oferta'];
$precio=$_POST['pantes'];
$promocion=$_POST['fecha'];
$hvideo=$_POST['hvideo'];
$certifica=$_POST['certifica02'];
$nponente=$_POST['nponente'];
$introponen=$_POST['inponente'];
$textointro=$_POST['textintro'];







$miconsulta ="INSERT INTO cursos (titulo, imagenp, ofer, pantes, certifica2, contenido, imagenvideo, url, duración, horas, tintro, foto_ponente, name_ponente, intro_ponente, titulo_impacto, sub_titulo_impacto, valoración, que_aprendere, requisitos) VALUES ('" .$titulo ."','" .$slider ."','" .$oferta ."','" .$precio ."','" .$certifica ."','" .$descripcion ."','" .$imagenvideo ."','" .$url ."','" .$promocion ."','" .$hvideo ."','" .$textointro ."','" .$fponente ."','" .$nponente ."','" .$introponen ."','" .$imacto ."','" .$subimpacto ."','" .$valoracion ."','" .$aprendere ."','" .$requisitos ."')";

$resultado=mysqli_query($miconexion, $miconsulta);
//cerramos la conexión
mysqli_close($miconexion);

echo "<br/> Se agregó con éxito. </br></br>";
?>
```

Comment: Buen día, manejalo con try/catch para saber que error te esta generando cuando hace el insert con la bd, te relaciono a continuación un enlace con el fin de documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Revisa que los tipos de dato que estas recibiendo, sean tal cual en la Bd, tanto su tipo como te comento y su logitud, puedes hacerlo mediante un `var_dump`

Comment: haz un echo de **$miconsulta** y pruébalo directamente en la base de datos

Comment: Los datos son correctos, el echo de $miconsulta agrega que está insertando, pero en la base da datos no inserta NADA

Comment: ¿te has asegurado que la conexión a la BD se realiza correctamente?

Comment: La conexión a la BD está bien, pero hasta el día de hoy no sé porque no iserta. Tengo otro código con el mismo mecanismo para agregar usuarios y si inserta los usuarios en la BD sin embargo no inserta los cursos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema pasaba por tener definida en tu tabla algunos campos con un nombre no válido, por ejemplo "dirección" con tilde.
Mysql te devuelve el error de que el campo "dirección" no existe y la consulta falla.
Debes corregir los nombres de tus campos.

Saludos

Comment: Para que sea bien recibida la respuesta coloca un ejemplo

Comment: No puedo poner un ejemplo porque la solución no depende del código que está en la pregunta. Es netamente un problema de los nombres de los campos en la tabla como describía arriba :/